# How can I make my own components in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, components, designer

How can I make a component that resides in the components tray like the Timer? So that you can place them from the toolbox but they are not visible on the form. Hopefully this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a class that inherits from `System.ComponentModel.Component`

Comment: Thanks, I made a Component for system-wide hot keys using this.